# How do I count frequency of each categorical variable in a column in pyspark dataframe for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to count the frequency of each category in a column and replace the values in the column with the frequency count. I want to do this for multiple columns in pyspark for a pyspark dataframe.

For example, consider the following dataframe:

```
+-------+-------+-------+  
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+-------+-------+-------+  
|   a   |   f   |   g   |  
|   c   |   e   |   a   |  
|   a   |   d   |   g   |  
|   a   |   d   |   g   |  
|   b   |   f   |   b   |  
|   c   |   d   |   g   |  
|   b   |   d   |   c   |  
|   a   |   d   |   g   |  
|   b   |   f   |   g   |  
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to convert this pyspark dataframe into the following:

```
+-------+-------+-------+  
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+-------+-------+-------+ 
|   4   |   3   |   6   |
|   2   |   1   |   1   |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|   3   |   2   |   1   |
|   2   |   5   |   6   |
|   3   |   5   |   1   |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|   3   |   2   |   6   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have the following code:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet(data)
df.show()

+-------+-------+-------+
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   a   |   f   |   g   |
|   c   |   e   |   a   |
|   a   |   d   |   g   |
|   a   |   d   |   g   |
|   b   |   f   |   b   |
|   c   |   d   |   g   |
|   b   |   d   |   c   |
|   a   |   d   |   g   |
|   b   |   f   |   g   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I can count the frequencies for each column using a for-loop using the following code:

```py
df.groupby('col_1').count().toDF('category', 'count').show()
```

I understand that I can do this for every column and glue the results together. I am wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with a [window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l = [
(   'a'   ,   'f'   ,   'g'   ),
(   'c'   ,   'e'   ,   'a'   ),
(   'a'   ,   'd'   ,   'g'   ),
(   'a'   ,   'd'   ,   'g'   ),
(   'b'   ,   'f'   ,   'b'   ),
(   'c'   ,   'd'   ,   'g'   ),
(   'b'   ,   'd'   ,   'c'   ),
(   'a'   ,   'd'   ,   'g'   ),
(   'b'   ,   'f'   ,   'g'  )
]

columns = ['col_1', 'col_2','col_3']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)


for column in columns:
    df = df.withColumn(column, F.count(column).over(Window.partitionBy(column)))

df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+-----+-----+-----+ 
|col_1|col_2|col_3| 
+-----+-----+-----+ 
|    4|    3|    6| 
|    3|    3|    6| 
|    4|    5|    6| 
|    4|    5|    6| 
|    4|    5|    6| 
|    2|    5|    6| 
|    3|    5|    1| 
|    3|    3|    1| 
|    2|    1|    1|
+-----+-----+-----+
```